# Overflow in implicit constant conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working with Objective-C and am getting the error `Overflow in implicit constant conversion`.  In my class header file, I define:

```
#define kNoLabelTag 9595959595959
```

Then, in my implementation file, I get the error on the following line:

```
if ( [self.view viewWithTag:kNoLabelTag] == nil )
```

Does this mean that all `#define`'d items are defined as NSStrings or some such?  If this is wrong, what is the *right* way to define integers?

Comment: Is 12345 the actual value you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm just using some random number, 12345 works for now.

Comment: @Neal L: The actual code is important. If we use "some random number", we might not get the same error as you. Does your code actually contain the precise line `#define kNoLabelTag 12345`?

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize.  I revised the question to use the actual number I typed in.

Comment: Is this 32 bit?  Your number is much larger than 2^32 - 1 (The largest unsigned 32 bit integer).

Comment: Interesting, changing the #define to `#define kNoLabelTag 135` takes away the warning. Post as an answer so I can accept and give credit where it's due.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your number is much larger than 2^32 - 1 (The largest unsigned 32 bit integer).

Comment: Yes, it's 32-bit — all iOS devices are. For the OP's reference: Specifically, an NSInteger cannot be greater than 2147483647. The number in question is several thousand times greater.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, I missed the iphone tag so I didn't make any assumptions.

Comment: So when the compiler evaluates `#define kNoLabelTag 135`, does it turn kNoLabelTag into an NSString, or a more primitive type?

Comment: It replaces all instances of kNoLabelTag with the integer 135.  If you had #define kNoLabelTag "135" I think it would be a NSString but I may be mistaken on that.  However, I think viewWithTag takes an integer as its argument so doing that would probably cause an error.

Comment: @Neal L: The compiler doesn't evaluate that line — the preprocessor does. It literally replaces every occurrence of the token `kNoLabelTag` with `135`. By the time it gets to the compiler, it's as if you had just written `135` in the first place. It's just like copy-and-paste, only the computer does it for you.